# mySQL_query not updating tables

Tags: php, sql

I have the following bit of PHP that is supposed to read entries from a form and then update the corresponding data table as well as attach the username of the logged in user, but for some reason our database isn't updating.

```
$Date = $_POST["Date"];
$Description = $_POST["Description"];
$Hour = (float)$_POST["Lat"];
$Min = (float)$_POST["Lon"];
$Username = $_SESSION['username'];
mysql_connect("localhost", "dbusername", "dbpass");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$connect) or die( "Unable to select database");

$sql = ("INSERT INTO Table (Date, Description, Hour, Min, Username)
VALUES ($Date, $Description, $Lat, $Lon, $Username)");

if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);

echo $Date;
echo $Description;
echo $Hour;
echo $Min; 
echo $Username;
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: No I haven't been, there aren't any new rows being created in the database is the main problem

Comment: Could you post the result of `echo $sql;` as well as the results of the mysql query: `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name` where `tbl_name` is the name of your table?

Answer (score 4):

You have not enclosed your query input variables in single quotes.

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO Table (Date, Description, Hour, Min, Username)
  VALUES ('$Date', '$Description', '$Lat', '$Lon', '$Username')");
```

You have called `mysql_error()` on query failure, presumably, it printed a syntax error near the first Date input value.

You MUST also escape your `$_POST` variables with `mysql_real_escape_string()` before passing them to the query, to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks.

```
$Date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Date"]);
$Description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Description"]);
// You might want to check sane bounds for these float values 
// in addition  to casting them as floats
$Hour = (float)$_POST["Lat"];
$Min = (float)$_POST["Lon"];
// Hopefully $Username is already sane, but escape to be safe
$Username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
```

When calling `mysql_select_db()`, the second parameter is optional, and indeed you have not defined `$connect` in your code. I suspect you meant:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "dbusername", "dbpass");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$connect) or die( "Unable to select database");
```

Comment: do I need to do this like this?
$Date = mysql_real_escape_string($_Post("Date")) 

or should I use a different expression? Thank you for the quick response

Comment: @MadMoney I've added it all above.

Comment: I updated the code and ran a test value of 
Date:12/11/2012
Description: Example
Hour: 10
Min: 50
and the logged in user was ExampleUser

the website returned me the following error:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , 10, 50, )' at line 2.

Does this represent a problem with the float? Again thank you so much for helping me crack this. I'm so lost on this kind of stuff.

Comment: 2 things: MySQL expects dates as `YYYY-MM-DD` (2012-12-11). The error points to something wrong with the Description field, possibly a missing quote at the end of it, or an extra quote.

Answer (score 0):

Um, lots of great suggestions here but there is one glaring problem with the code as you posted it.  You are assigning latitude and longitude values from the post to php variable named $Hour and $Min respectively...

```
$Hour = (float)$_POST["Lat"];
$Min = (float)$_POST["Lon"];
```

However, when you write the query you are referring to those values as $Lat and $Lon respectively....

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO Table (Date, Description, Hour, Min, Username)
VALUES ($Date, $Description, $Lat, $Lon, $Username)");
```

Nowhere in the code that you posted do you actually assign a value to $Lat or $Lon, yet you wish to assign their values to parameters of your query.  In essence you are calling variable in your query that do not exist.