# Undefined variable error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to integrate amazon api into my website, so far I have managed to have it navigate to the correct xml part and store that as an variable however i am now trying to insert this varibable into my mysql database and it is giving me this error

Notice:  Undefined variable: sql_select in
Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object

what am i doing wrong?

Entire Code

```
define('INCLUDED', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "HIDDENFORPRIVACY";
$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "HIDDENFORPRIVACY";

$base_url = "http://free.apisigning.com/onca/xml?";
$url_params = array('Operation'=>"ItemLookup",'Service'=>"AWSECommerceService",
 'AWSAccessKeyId'=>$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,'AssociateTag'=>"HIDDENFORPRIVACY",
 'Version'=>"2011-08-01",'Availability'=>"Available",'ItemId'=>"0273702440",
 'ItemPage'=>"1",'ResponseGroup'=>"EditorialReview", 'Title'=>"Accounting and Finance for Non-Specialists 5th Edition");

// Add the Timestamp
$url_params['Timestamp'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());

// Sort the URL parameters
$url_parts = array();
foreach(array_keys($url_params) as $key)
    $url_parts[] = $key."=".$url_params[$key];
sort($url_parts);

// Construct the string to sign
//$string_to_sign = "GET\nhttp://free.apisigning.com/".implode("&",$url_parts);
//$string_to_sign = str_replace('+','%20',$string_to_sign);
//$string_to_sign = str_replace(':','%3A',$string_to_sign);
//$string_to_sign = str_replace(';',urlencode(';'),$string_to_sign);

// Sign the request
//$signature = hash_hmac("sha256",$string_to_sign,$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,TRUE);

// Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
//$signature = base64_encode($signature);
//$signature = str_replace('+','%2B',$signature);
//$signature = str_replace('=','%3D',$signature);
//$signature = str_replace(';',urlencode(';'),$string_to_sign);
$url_string = implode("&",$url_parts);
$url = $base_url.$url_string;
//print $url;


$ch = curl_init();                   //this part we set up curl 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$xml_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header('Content-type: application/xml');  //specify as xml to not display as one long string
echo $xml_response; 

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_response);  //time to echo back the correct piece of data

$editorialReview = $xml->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview->Content;

$variable = '<p>Editorial review: '.html_entity_decode($editorialReview).'</p>'."\n";
echo $variable;

$sql_select = mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "auctions
            (amazon_description) VALUES
            ('" . $variable . "')");
            echo ($sql_select);
```

this does not send errors, but the mysql database shows no change

Comment: What is `$sql_select`? Where is it coming from? Your code does not show that.

Comment: Try this: $sql_select->query("INSERT INTO {DB_PREFIX} auctions (amazon_description) VALUES ('{$variable}')");

Comment: Nice [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) hole...

Comment: @zi42 edited i am using the amazon api so idk if this would still be a vulnerability as it is only going to be run by the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Undefined variable" indicates that you have not initialized the object.

From the code you printed it seems that $sql_select **should** be a string which has the select statement.

So you need to do something like :

```
$variable = '<p>Editorial review: '.html_entity_decode($editorialReview).'</p>'."\n";
echo $variable;

$sql_select .= "INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "auctions
            (amazon_description) VALUES
            ('" . $variable . "')";

$DB_object->query($sql_select);
```

Please post the entire code so that the solution can be accurately found out.

Comment: Because I'm not sure of the entire code and there might be pre SQL comments and hintsor other previous SQL statements to be executed in batch.

Comment: @JackBrown i have edited my post to include entire code, the current code produces no errors but the mysql database does not update correctly

Comment: Alright, this is a different & answered issue. @Frank, Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394695/mysql-query-not-updating-tables